# PrimeNG button not display when there are 2 input text inside the form (but display well with only one input text)

Tags: primeng

I got a weird bug, my p-button is not display well when I have this code :

```
<form style = "text-align: left;">

    <input pInputText  type = "text" [(ngModel)] = "newUserFirstname"  />
    <br/><br/>

    <input pInputText  type = "text" [(ngModel)] = "newUserLastname"  />
    <br/><br/>

    <p-button label="Submit" ></p-button>
  
</form>
```

See the result :

[image]

(If I click on the button, its appearance becomes normal)

If I remove one of the input text (any one), it displays well :

```
<form style = "text-align: left;">

    <input pInputText  type = "text" [(ngModel)] = "newUserFirstname"  />
    <br/><br/>

    <p-button label="Submit" ></p-button>
  
</form>
```

See the result :

[image]

Very strange

Any clue ?

Thanks

Comment: In the screenshot there are also labels which don't appear in your code example. Can you copy a more complete code example, including the labels and any other elements you used?

Comment: I uplodated the wrong screenshot sorry. I reuploaded.

Comment: You must have an error in the console telling you what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The following is working for me:

```
<form style = "text-align: left;">
    <div>
        <label for='firstName'>First:&nbsp;</label>
        <input pInputText  type = "text" [(ngModel)] = "firstName"  />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for='lastName'>Last:&nbsp;</label>
        <input pInputText  type = "text" [(ngModel)] = "lastName"  />
    </div>
    <div>
        <p-button label="Submit"></p-button>
    </div>
</form>
```

But, I have seen in changing the view, the button reduced to a small rectangle.

I normally use the directive form of the button:

```
<button type='button' pButton label="Submit"></button>
```